# Creating a backend to issue discount codes

Tags: ruby, backend, discounts

How can I create a system/backend that will generate a discount code then allow that code to be distributed/retrieved to/from a 3rd party system?

Comment: If you don't need a GUI, but want another program (web or otherwise) to be able to query your app to retrieve the discount code. how about using a web service? That would be universally accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a web application and expose its functionality via API. Then protect the API with auth (for example OAuth), write documentation and provide it to 3rd party.

I suggest reading on RESTful APIs and using Ruby on Rails.